# How to create a program that returns a boolean value without printing it?

Tags: java

So I have a task to create a program that can tell which kind of triangle it is based on the numbers entered. Everyother program we have done was done using a text file pop up in our compiler this one however he wants to be done through the program its self, I think. So for example one of the methods he wants is Public Boolean isTriangle. I however am unsure how to add this to a class, everything done up into this point has been done in one block. I will paste what I have although I know a lot of it is wrong. Honestly I am very lost and could use any guidance. He wrote the Public boolean thing on the hand out so I think it is right but I get an identifier expected error. I know this is probably convoluted and I am missing base knowledge. Thank you so much for any help

```
{
      public Triangle( double a, double b, double c)
    {

        boolean isTriangle, isScalene, isEquilateral, isRight, isIsosceles ;

        isTriangle = (a+b)>= c && (a+c)>= b && (c+b)>= a ;
        isScalene = (a != b) || (b != c) || (a != c) ;
        isEquilateral = ( a == b ) && ( c == b );
        isRight = (Math.pow(a,2)) + (Math.pow(b,2)) == Math.pow(c,2);
        isIsosceles = ( a == b) || ( a == c) || ( b == c );//


    Public boolean isTriangle ()
   { if ( isTriangle == true)

    }
}
```

Comment: Create two methods: `isTriangle()` and `main()`.  Implement the logic inside `isTriangle()` and then call it from `main`.

Comment: So how would I do that? You can use a different example so you aren't just doing my work for me. He said he wanted it exactly like it is on the handout which had Public Trianlge

Comment: 1. move your method outside of your constructor. 2. in [main()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) instantiate Triangle and then use this new instance to call your IsTriangle() method.

Comment: I'm sorry so what would be the constructor in the example above. So would there not be a Public Triangle? That is how we've always done it

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably have a little mess in that class. Not sure, but I think you need to create a Triangle class, something like this...

```
public class Triangle {

   // private variables of the Triangle class
   private boolean isTriangle, isScalene, isEquilateral, isRight, isIsosceles;

   // constructor of the Triangle class
   public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
     isTriangle = (a + b) >= c && (a + c) >= b && (c + b) >= a;
     isScalene = (a != b) || (b != c) || (a != c);
     isEquilateral = (a == b) && (c == b);
     isRight = (Math.pow(a, 2)) + (Math.pow(b, 2)) == Math.pow(c, 2);
     isIsosceles = (a == b) || (a == c) || (b == c);
   }

   // isTriangle() method of the Triangle class
   public boolean isTriangle() {
     return isTriangle;
   }



  /*
   *  you can add more methods here,
   *  e.g. isScalene(), isEquilateral(), ...
   *  
   */


}
```

And if you want to test this class, I would create an other class with main method, where you can create Triangle objects and call their methods...

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        // creating triangle objects from Triangle class...
        Triangle t1 = new Triangle(3, 3, 5);
        Triangle t2 = new Triangle(3, 1, 1);        
        // testing the methods of the triangle objects...
        System.out.println("Is t1 a triangle? " + t1.isTriangle());
        System.out.println("Is t2 a triangle? " + t2.isTriangle());     
    }

}
```

Of course, if you want to do it in one class, you can move the whole **main** method from the **App** class to the **Triangle** class and use only that class (in that case you do not need the App class).

Comment: Does private vs public in the booleans matter here?

Comment: They should be private, because you probably do not want them to be modified from other class, like from the App class. You can access the values of those variables from App class only through the isTriangle() and other methods.

Comment: If you set those variable public (which you can, but it is not the correct way of making the Triangle class), then you can access them directly from the App class, e.g. you can set t2.isTriangle=true; which is not correct!

Comment: alright thank you very much, I think I have nearly everything set up  but it says that I have to use toString, how would I do that because there is no characters?

Comment: The toString is a method which returns the String representation of an object, you do not need any characters, it returns a string. In your case you can add it into Triangle and use it to print triangles in main method. Here is a good example: http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method